# Getting Error while conversion of wsdl to JAR file

Tags: java, soap, jar, wsdl

I need to convert the wsdl file to JAR file.I am converting it from the command prompt. I am using the following command for conversion.

```
java –classpath pathToJAR/wsc-22.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc pathToWsdl/WsdlFilename pathToOutputJar/OutputJarFilename
```

But after using the above command I am getting the following error stack:

```
C:\Users>java -classpath "D:\Pravin\Project Related\wsc-23.jar" com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc "D:\Pravin\Project Related\Enterprise.wsdl" "D:\Generated JAR\enterprise11.jar"
[WSC23][wsdlc.run:348]Created temp dir: C:\Users\PRAVIN~1.HCL\AppData\Local\Temp\wsdlc-temp-2668333477894471816-dir
[WSC23][wsdlc.<init>:110]Generating Java files from schema ...
[WSC23][wsdlc.<init>:110]Generated 366 java files.
[WSC23][wsdlc.compileTypes:298]Compiling to target default...
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0-ea). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include
your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RESOURCE_VARIABLE
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol.getConstValue(Symbol.java:1002)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitVarDef(Attr.java:782)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:716)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:409)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:396)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:458)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:3077)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:3000)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:2936)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1122)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:842)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:801)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:409)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:139)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc$Compiler.compile(wsdlc.java:491)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.compileTypes(wsdlc.java:298)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.<init>(wsdlc.java:119)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:348)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.main(wsdlc.java:339)
[WSC23][wsdlc.compileTypes:298]Compiled 369 java files.
[WSC23][wsdlc.<init>:120]Generating jar file ... D:\Generated JAR\enterprise11.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PRAVIN~1.HCL\AppData\Local\Temp\wsdlc-temp-2668333477894471816-dir\com\sforce\soap\enterprise\fault\ApiFault.class (The system cannot
 find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.addFileToJar(wsdlc.java:244)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.generateJarFile(wsdlc.java:223)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.<init>(wsdlc.java:120)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:348)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.main(wsdlc.java:339)
```

JAR file getting created but it doesn't containing any package component or classes.
Could you please explain me what kind of this error is?
Please reply ASAP.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no problem with command. Have you tried it with jdk 1.6, it worked for me.